# Vim Batch Rename

Tags: vim

I want to batch-change file extensions with Vim.  I found [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Bulk_rename_files_with_Vim), which advises:

To change all .JPEG extensions to .jpg:

```
:%s/.*/mv -i & &/g
:%s/.JPEG$/.jpg/g
```

Unfortunately it doesn't explain why this works.  I have used `:%s` in basic situations, but can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/.*/mv -i & &/g
```

Replaces every line in the document (say, "line"), and replaces it by "mv -i line line". `.*` is a regex saying "any character, repeated any number of times". `&` means "what has been found".

```
:%s/.JPEG$/.jpg/g
```

Searches for `.JPEG` at the end of any line (hence the `$`) and replaces it by `.jpg`

So if you have a document with

```
foo.JPEG
bar.png
baz.jpg
```

After the first command, it'll become

```
mv -i foo.JPEG foo.JPEG
mv -i bar.png bar.png
mv -i baz.jpg baz.jpg
```

Then after the second command,

```
mv -i foo.JPEG foo.jpg
mv -i bar.png bar.png
mv -i baz.jpg baz.jpg
```

Comment: Tip: to rename in bash, use `ls *.JPEG | while read i; do mv "$i" "${i%.JPEG}.jpg"; done`

Comment: Unfortunately I only have Vim and not bash at work.  But this makes complete sense, thank you!  And is actually stuff that I knew--I just wasn't putting it together properly.

Answer (score 2):

You're focusing just on the `:substitute` command to rename; the crucial finishing act is

```
:%!bash
```

which sends the rename shell commands (that's why `mv` is prepended to each file name) to an external shell for execution.

Basically, this trick uses Vim's excellent shell integration (both for reading a list of files from standard input, and for piping text through an external command) to turn file renaming into a text editing task. A downside is that it's not portable; the given commands only work on Unix-family operating systems; for Windows, the commands would need to be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

The first command expects that the file consists of a single filename/path per line. The `&` is a references the matched expression (what `.*` has matched).

So it turns:

```
foo.JPEG
```

into:

```
mv -i foo.JPEG foo.JPEG
```

The second command then matches all `.JPEG` at the end of line (that's what the `$` anchor is doing). So all `.JPEG` at the end of lines are then replaced by `.jpg`. You then have:

```
mv -i foo.JPEG foo.jpg
```